# php, force file download, php adds some html text to file

Tags: php

This is simple download script, it does not work 100% properly -  When I download a txt file, the script changes it's content to this:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: LAST_ACTIVITY in **/home/an011500/www_root/file.php** on line **9**

```
if($login_result)
    {
        ftp_chdir($connection, $uploaded_files);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$result['file_name'].'"'); 
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('./uploaded_files/' .$result['ftp_file_name']));
        readfile('./uploaded_files/' .$result['ftp_file_name']);
    }
    else
    {
          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('login failed');</script>";
    }
```

So the file is corrupted.. also images are corrupted, but mp3 songs do work after download.

The LAST_ACTIVITY is not existing Session..... I've set error reporting to:
    ini_set('display_errors','true');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
So php displays errors. But why it adds the error to file?

Anyone can help me?

Edit: 
first 9 lines

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
require_once('db-config.php');
require_once('main-classes.php');
ini_set('display_errors','true');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$time_var = time();
$Checker = new Checker($time_var, $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['email'], $DB_CONNECTION);
```

Comment: So show us lines 1-9 of your file.php script

Comment: So, what is on line 9 of /home/an011500/www_root/file.php ?

Comment: It does not work properly even if the session exists

Comment: In a production environment you don't want erros to be displayed, so you must set `display_errors` to false. However, this is not the error. You should check the existence of the session variables before creating the `Checker`.